# How to perform client-side-only operations in PrimeFaces?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

Let's say there is a website that displays some information using metric units (left side) and does a calculation on them, e.g. an online grocery store:

```
Apples - 1 kg               |    Apples - 2 pound
Pears  - 2 kg               |    Pears  - 4 pounds
Oranges - 0.5 kg            |    Oranges - 1 pound
---------------             |    -----------------
total:   3.5kg              |    total:   7 pounds
```

And there is a button to toggle metric/US units. When toggled, it should change the measures (right side). This can be simply achieved by making an ajax call to a managed bean, which would then return converted values.

Is there a way to achieve this, without too much hassle, on the client side, without making a call to the server? The idea is to avoid using JS frameworks which are not SEO friendly by default.

P.S. No need for code, just a general approach using PrimeFaces/JSF, name of some JS library, etc.

Comment: Things get really sketchy when you use a server-sided framework and then want to go out of your way to prevent round trips. You already answer your own question; if you want to leave the comfort of the JDK and the object model that JSF maintains for you on the server, you'll have to tank the entire thing into Javascript - including said model so you can operate on the data using javascript code. Primefaces uses JQuery itself, so you can use that for your own purposes too without having to include additional libraries.

Comment: @Mike: you can use the onstart attribute of primefaces ajax and convert the values in a js function and set it back to the outputtext using its innerHTML.

Comment: @evamiriam: that might work, but if you want the user to be able to store its preference (metric vs collonial/imperial) unitsvand show that by default, the additional work to also have it on the client side (how often does one switch?) is imo very low. I'd just do it server side

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and suggestions. @Kukeltje that's a good point with how often do these changes happen, given this use case.

Comment: @Gimby I'm not quite happy with giving away everything that JDK offers for that specific functionality. I'd be glad to hear more opinions on this.